# Custom TextView is not being shown

Tags: android, textview, android-view, visibility

This is my first question on here so don't go too hard on me :D
My plan is to make a seat plan for teachers, where the students are being shown. This seat plan is being created dynamically from a SQLiteDatabase. While approaches with GridView/GridLayout/TableLayout have all failed, now I'm just having a vertical LinearLayout, adding horizontal ones to it.

Now, in order to know the position of a student, I've been trying to extend from TextView, a class called SchuelerView (Schüler = student in German) that does the same as a normal TextView, simply with one more attribute: a Schueler. 
If I do everything the same way, just by using TextViews, it works, but when it comes to my custom class, it doesn't work.

This is the SchuelerView code:

```
public class SchuelerView extends TextView {

    private Schueler schueler;
    private int posx, posy;

    public SchuelerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SchuelerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public int getPosx() {
        return posx;
    }

    public int getPosy() {
        return posy;
    }

    public void setPosx(int posx) {
        this.posx = posx;
    }

    public void setPosy(int posy) {
        this.posy = posy;
    }

    public void setSchueler(Schueler s) {
        schueler = s;
        posx = schueler.getPosx();
        posy = schueler.getPosy();
    }

    public Schueler getSchueler() {
        return schueler;
    }

}
```

And this is the method that is using these views:

```
public void schuelerZuGrid() {

    lv.removeAllViews(); // Vertikales LinearLayout
    lv.setWeightSum(reihen);

    for(int i = 0; i < reihen; i++) {

        LinearLayout lh = new LinearLayout(this);
        lh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        lh.setWeightSum(spalten); // DESIGN
        lv.addView(lh);

        for(int j = 0; j < spalten; j++) {

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT vorname, nachname, posx, posy, sid FROM Schueler, Hat "
                    + "WHERE Hat.schuelerid = Schueler.sid AND Hat.kfid =" + kfid + " AND posx="+j+" AND posy="+i, null);

            if(c.getCount() > 0) {

                c.moveToFirst();
                String vorname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("vorname"));
                String nachname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nachname"));
                int posx = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("posx"));
                int posy = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("posy"));
                int sid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("sid"));
                c.close();

                Schueler schueler = new Schueler(vorname, nachname, posx, posy, sid);

                SchuelerView t = new SchuelerView(this);
                t.setSchueler(schueler);

                t.setText(vorname + " " + nachname);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // DESIGN
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1); // DESIGN
                t.setLayoutParams(lp); // DESIGN

                t.setOnClickListener(this);

                lh.addView(t);
            } else {
                SchuelerView t = new SchuelerView(this);

                t.setPosx(j);
                t.setPosy(i);

                t.setText("/");
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // DESIGN
                t.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1)); // DESIGN
                t.setOnClickListener(this);

                lh.addView(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I've said, the only error I get is that I don't see anything on the Activity. However, the SQL statements all are being executed correctly, and as I've said, doing everything the same way, just with TextViews, works out fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: I put it in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/73gx9xP6

Comment: each `SchuelerView` has height == 0, like this: `com.kvs.SchuelerView{39b5cb3 V.ED..C.. ......ID 720,0-960,0}`, try `lh.addView(t, params)` where `params` are set to MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: Should I remove the line where I'm setting the params of the View? Or should I do both? I'm asking because I'm currently not at the computer, else I could just find out

Comment: first try to change the y param to wrap content

Comment: you mean height param? ive done that, doesnt change anything, also if both are set to WRAP_CONTENT
edit: forgot to mention that in the dump the last digit again is 0

Comment: what happens if you set height for testing for some fixed value like 64?

Comment: it still doesnt work then. i found out why though, it was the very top linearlayout that had "0dp" set as height. this was made in order to have every sub view have the same height (match_parent didnt work) and i got suggested to use height == 0dp and weight == 1... anyway, this has been solved, thank you :)
if you want you can leave it as an answer and ill mark it as the correct answer